# Evaluating groups of cell values with an Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question for using logic in an excel formula. I have 6 columns of text data and I want to evaluate all of them at once and assign some type of value in a separate cell adjacent to the columns. For instance, let's say I have 6 cells in a filled in with a month value, say "May" and I just want to detect if there is a different month in the group (eg 'June') in a separate adjacent cell. How could I use a formula to detect such a difference in a group, etc.

Below is a example with the output from a desired formula indicating whether the group of months is consistent or not.

May May May May May May   "Consistent Months"

May May May June May May   "Inconsistent Months"

Comment: give a proper example with real data

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

`=IF(AND(A1=B1, B1=C1, C1=D1, .....), "Consistent Months", "Inconsistent Months")`

This will test whether all of the values in the range A1 -> *X1*  are identical. You can add conditions similarly to test whether the cells are text, numbers or contain a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

I would use COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:F1,"<>"&A1)>0,"Inconsistent","Consistent")
```